# Wiring the callback function to onload event for body element failing

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javaScript and was going through various techniques of wiring callback functions to the events.

In the technique to separate all JS codes from html and wire all the callback functions in `window.onload` block (highly recommended by Head First JavaScript, i'm following that), the wiring of body element for onload event is not working.

I'm expecting two alert boxes, having `Hii` followed by other with `Hello` (when i click the button), but i'm getting only Hello (by button click) but before that i'm not getting `Hii` alert box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fun1 () {
            alert("Hii");
        }

        function fun2 () {
            alert("hello");
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onload = function () {
                fun1();
            };

            document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function () {
                fun2();
            };
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Click">
</body>
</html>
```

Second part of the question;

In the following code where i move `onload` for `body` element to the html code itself, then i get only one alert box with `Hii` (as expected), but then the `onlick` event on the button doesn't work as expected which alert box with `Hello`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fun1 () {
            alert("Hii");
        }

        function fun2 () {
            alert("hello");
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function () {
                fun2();
            };
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="fun1()";>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Click">
</body>
</html>
```

This uncertain behaviour is troubling me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `window.onload` is that it triggers after the `body.onload` event. This explains why `fun1` is never invoked: by the time you attach the `onload` event handler to the `body` tag, that event had already been triggered -- before you attached your handler to it.

One way to improve on this, is to listen to the `DOMContentLoaded` event. It will trigger before the `body.onload` event. In fact, you should only need to use `window.onload` when you really need the whole document content, including images to be loaded. `DOMContentLoaded` will trigger before that -- when the DOM tree is available.

So this should work:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.body.onload = function () {
        fun1();
    };

    document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function () {
        fun2();
    };
});
```

But there is really no reason to have a separate `body.onload` handler. You might as well do:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    fun1(); // call it when the DOM content is loaded.

    document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function () {
        fun2();
    };
});
```

And, ... it is best practice to assign event handlers with `addEventListener`, because it allows to attach more than one handler for the same event, and so different scripts do not have to interfere with eachother in that respect:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    fun1(); // call it when the DOM content is loaded.

    document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function () {
        fun2();
    });
});
```

A short-cut can be applied when you execute just one function in an event handler: instead of wrapping that call in an anonymous function, you might as well pass that function itself as a reference:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    fun1(); // call it when the DOM content is loaded.

    document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', fun2);
});
```